# How to join two dataframe with same category?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Now, I have two dataframe. I have use groupby. and count() function to export this dataframe(df1). When I used groupby. to count the total number of each category. It filtered out the category which the count is 0. How can I use Python to get the outcome?

However,I will like to have a dataframe which also required categories.

Original dataframe:

```
    Cat           UR3     VR1    VR    VR3
0   ATIDS         137.0   99.0   40.0  84.0
1   BasicCrane    2.0     8.0    3.0   1.0
2   Beam Sensor   27.0    12.0   13.0  14.0
3   CLPS          1.0     NaN    NaN   1.0
```

However,I will like to have a dataframe which also required categories.
(required categories: ATIDS, BasicCrane, LLP, Beam Sensor, CLPS, SPR)

Expected dataframe (The count number of 'LLP' and 'SPR' is 0)

```
    Cat           UR3     VR1    VR    VR3
0   ATIDS         137.0   99.0   40.0  84.0
1   BasicCrane    2.0     8.0    3.0   1.0
2   LLP           NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN
3   Beam Sensor   27.0    12.0   13.0  14.0
4   CLPS          1.0     NaN    NaN   1.0
5   SPR           NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> categories
['ATIDS', 'BasicCrane', 'LLP', 'Beam Sensor', 'CLPS', 'SPR']

>>> pd.merge(pd.DataFrame({'Cat': categories}), df, how='outer')
           Cat    UR3   VR1    VR   VR3
0        ATIDS  137.0  99.0  40.0  84.0
1   BasicCrane    2.0   8.0   3.0   1.0
2          LLP    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  Beam Sensor   27.0  12.0  13.0  14.0
4         CLPS    1.0   NaN   NaN   1.0
5          SPR    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could easily do is to fill NaN value with 0 'before' doing a groupby function. All zero data (previously NaN value) will be totally be counted as zero.

```
df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: I think this is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Oh, I might misunderstand the objective.